# Volume of the solid bounded by the planes (Checking the limits of the integral)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Find the volume $V$ of the solid bounded by the planes $x+y-z=3$ and $z=0$, and the cylinder $x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$. My calculations give

**Polar**
$$V = \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi/2} \int_{r=0}^{r=1} \int_{z=r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)-3}^{z=0} 2r \, \mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}r \, \mathrm{d} \, \theta$$

**Rectangular**
$$V = \int_{x=1}^{x=3} \int_{y=3-x}^{y=\sqrt{4(1-x^2)}} \int_{z=x+y-3}^{z=0} \, \mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}y \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Are these the correct limits?

Comment: The cross-section of this cylinder is an ellipse centered on the origin, which does not have a simple expression for $ \ r(\theta) \ $ .  Also, the tilted plane passes "below" the $ \ z = 0 \ $ plane and will require you to integrate all the way around the $ \ z-$ axis, so the angle integration limit is not correct. You will probably be better off working this out in rectangular coordinates.

Comment: Ok I tried it with rectangular coordinates is this correcct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The cross-section of the cylinder is an ellipse with a semi-axis of $ \  1 \ $ along the $ \ x-$ axis and a semi-axis of $ \  2 \ $ along the $ \ y-$ axis.  Unfortunately, the inclined plane $ \ z = x + y - 3 \ $ has its symmetry along a line making a 45º angle to the coordinate axes, so we don't catch any break from symmetry in making this volume integration.  The "vertical distance" from the tilted plane "upward" to the $ \ xy-$ plane ( $  z = 0  $ ) must be integrated over the full ellipse in the $ \ xy-$ plane, giving us

$$ \ \int_{-1}^{1}  \ \int_{-2 \sqrt{1-x^2}}^{+2 \sqrt{1-x^2}}  \ \int^0_{x+y-3}     \ \ dz \ dy \ dx \ \ . $$

I agree with some of your integration limits, but not all of them.  The integration is not as bad as it may initially appear, as one pair of terms cancels out and another term is an odd function of $ \ x \ $ ; the remaining portion of the integration can even be done "geometrically".

I find a value of $ \ 6 \pi \ $ , which **Alan** confirms in a comment below.  As a check, we can determine the minimum and maximum values of $ \ z \ $ over the ellipse, which occur on the curve itself at $ \ ( \ \pm \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{5}} \ , \ \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \ ) \ $ .  So the extremal values of $ \ z \ $ are $ \ ( \pm \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}) - 3 \ $ , giving an "average" over the ellipse of $ \ -3 \ $ .  Since the area of the ellipse is $ \ \pi \ \cdot \ 1 \ \cdot \ 2 \ $ , we can estimate the volume as $ \ |-3| \ \cdot \ 2 \pi \ = \ 6 \pi \ $ .

Comment: I get this exact expression , and $6\pi$ for an answer.

Comment: I agree (just found where I omitted a factor of 2); I also made a check I'll discuss which shows this value is reasonable.  Thanks for your comment!